# Find my span text using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
<body>
...
<div class="first-class">
  <ul class="container-class>
    <li>
      <a><span>Not it</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a><span>Target</span</a>
    </li>
```

I want to create an Xpath to find the word "target". The number of list elements can vary so I can't use the id because it will change dynamically.

Here's what I've tried:

```
".//*[@class='first-class']/ul[li a//(text)[contains(.,'Target')]]"
```

Comment: There are a myriad of ways to find something based on text, but you've not said what exactly you're trying to select.  Do you wish to select a `span`, `a`, `li`, ... or `div` element?

Comment: I'm trying to get where I can click the anchor in Selenium. I figured if I can find the text, and just perform click it would work.

Comment: Then see @Andersson's answer  (+1) to select the targeted `a` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below `XPath`:

```
//a[.="Target"]
```

or

```
//a[span="Target"]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//a[contains(@span,'Target')]
```

Should be all it takes.

Comment: `span` is not an attribute of `a`! I think you mean `//a[contains(span,'Target')]`